# Drag folder to .exe program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code. I managed to make my .py to .exe but when I want to drag and drop a folder with my files to compare them with other files, it won't work. Just creating my  output folder and exits the program. Here is the python code and where should I modify the code when I drag and drop the folder to execute the program? Thank you

```
import difflib
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
import time


ts = time.time()

fold1_path = input("First folder:")
path1 = []
path1.append(fold1_path)
list1 = list(Path(path1[0]).glob("*.htm"))
## Create empty folder for the result
x = os.path.expanduser("~")+ r"\Desktop\rezultat_script"
path = x
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

# Copy files into different folder for processing
files = list1.copy()
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(f, path)



fold2_path = input("Second folder:")
list2 = list(Path(fold2_path).glob("*.htm"))

def compare(folder1, folder2):
    for num in range(len(list1)):
        show_pre = "Before editing:"
        show_post = "After editing:"
        show_pre_lines = open(folder1[num]).readlines()
        show_post_lines = open(folder2[num]).readlines()
        difference = difflib.HtmlDiff(wrapcolumn=100).make_file(show_pre_lines, show_post_lines, show_pre, show_post)

    for file in range(len(folder1)):
        difference_report = open(folder1[file], "w+")
        difference_report.write(difference)
        difference_report.close()

fold3_path = list(Path(x).glob("*.htm"))

compare(fold3_path, list2)


print("Script done!")
te = time.time()
total_time = te-ts
print("Total time used: {:10.2f}".format(total_time))
```

Comment: You're fetching `fold1_path` from standard input, but when you drag a folder onto your EXE it most likely gets passed in as a command-line argument. Look at [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) instead

Comment: can you show me please in the code where to modify?

Comment: `import sys` `if len(sys.argv) == 2: #acquire fold1_path from argv... else: #acquire from input() like you're already doing`